Microsoft Graph HTTP Get request not showing expected results
I am trying to list all of the sites in a particular tenant simply using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http documentation.
However, when I do a get request, my value fields are empty. There are SharePoint sites on this tenant.
The API has Reports.Read.All and Sites.Read.All with admin permissions granted. This is odd since when I attempt to list all root sites, I get a 403 forbidden error.



Used postman to check my API permissions.

Did you double check access_token?

I have found the answer. I am using the incorrect GET request. Would be good if Microsoft could update their documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-getallsites?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
Instead of GET /sites as documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http I need to use GET /sites/getAllSites.
Thank you Microsoft.
